# How do i add cronjob entry dynamically through my application code (i.e NodeJS) on to a ubuntu based container?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, cron, containers

I have a nodejs app based on microservice architecture, which i am planning to run on kubernetes cluster by containerizing it.
I need this app to query from db of all the cron entries and add these cron entries to crontab on the same server as in where my application is running.

When i  query for all my cron entries and i get a list of cron jobs, as below :

```js
1 * * * * root node /home/project/app.js 103
1 * * * * root node /home/project/app.js 104
1 * * * * root node /home/project/app.js 105
```

I need to add these cron jobs dynamically on to a server( server in here is my app container, which is based on ubuntu image) when ever i do a DB query to list jobs.
How do i add these cron jobs from my application to my server?
Is there a direct solution to this or can this be done with any library in NodeJS?

I looked through shelljs lib for NodeJS, i found it bit complex so couldn't try with it.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend witing multiple cron entries for one application - because if you have thousends of entries for multiple apps it will get very large and adding some by your self will become very hard.

When the required execution time never changes, just create a "cron.sh"-file in your node js root file directory and write all commands into it.

crontab -e: `1 * * * * root /home/project/cron.sh > /home/project/cron.log`

Content of /home/project/cron.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Change directory:
cd /home/project/
# Run the script with all parameters
node ./app.js 103
node ./app.js 104
node ./app.js 105
```

Dont forget to `chmod 0770` cron.sh in order to be able to write to it and, because you seem to run this cron as root, prevent other users to execute commands as root.

/e: for changing crontab file directly you can use the following shell code to first export, modify and import jobs again:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const fs  = require('fs');
// Read content of file
function ReadCronFile(cb) {
    exec("crontab -l", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        cb(stdout);
    });
}
// Write a crontab file
function WriteCronFile(data, cb) {
    fs.writeFile("tmp.txt", data, function(err) {
        exec("crontab tmp.txt", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            fs.unlink("tmp.txt", function(err) {
                cb();
            });
        });
    });
}
// Example usage
ReadCronFile(function(data) { console.log(data); });
WriteCronFile("...", function() { console.log("Done!"); });
```

Note: code untested
Or, with Promise (tested by OP)

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const fs  = require('fs');
// Read content of file
function ReadCronFile() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        exec("crontab -l", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if(err) return reject(err);
            else return resolve(stdout);
        });
    });
}
// Write a crontab file
function WriteCronFile(data) {
    fs.writeFile("tmp.txt", data, function(err) {
        if(err) return reject(err);
        exec("crontab tmp.txt", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            fs.unlink("tmp.txt", function(err) {
                if(err) return reject(err);
                else return resolve();
            });
        });
    });
}
// Example usage
ReadCronFile().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
WriteCronFile("...").then(function() {
    console.log("Done!");
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

For parsing crontab file you can use https://github.com/harrisiirak/cron-parser

Comment: @tinosys - The cron time i mentioned is a sample, these jobs can be of any time and different scripts. My requirement is to add these cron jobs which i query from database in to the server crontab. How do i post that cron entries to server crontab through my NodeJS application is the question.

Comment: Updated the answer using callback- & promise-style; the code above is untested, but should work in theory

Comment: @tinosys - will try with this first and then will come back. thank you

Comment: @tinosys - thank you, it worked, i used promise-style and used fs.unlink instead of fs.removeFile.

Comment: No problem; updated the answer with the corrections you made; please flag it as anwer if it answered your question. By the way, my username is "tionsys", but my first name is Tino, you were right with that :D

Comment: I did :) i am sorry @tionsys, but i will stick with 'tino' :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Try [Cron NPM Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

It's very easy to start with and has a lot of feature to implement complex jobs.

Comment: Sidenote: this requires the script registering the crons to run always, e.g. by installing it as daemon.